# python segregating lines based on the hostname from a composite logfile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking forward a way to read a log file and read the hostname based on column 5 and hold the hostname with all iteration until new come, or say Just mark a double space when new name found but it needs to print the entire line.

**Just reading the file:**

```
$ cat test.py
with open("file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        fr = f.read()
        print(fr)
```

**File content output:**

```
$ ./test.py
Jul 18 14:30:02 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:47:45 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:48:48 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:49:51 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 17:17:10 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:46:43 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:48:49 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:50:01 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:51:16 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:52:52 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 22:13:20 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 22:13:20 hw070 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 22:17:26 hw070 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 20:16:21 hw071 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 20:17:24 hw071 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 20:18:27 hw071 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 20:43:07 hw073 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 15:45:59 hw074 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 17:17:12 hw074 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 01:20:20 hw074 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 16:16:01 hw079 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:17:56 hw079 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 17 04:34:08 anujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003  not responding, still trying
Jul 17 21:18:42 sanujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003  not responding, still trying
Jul 18 01:36:00 sanujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003  not responding, still trying
Jul 18 04:16:10 sanujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003  not responding, still trying
```

**Desired output:**

```
Jul 18 14:30:02 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:47:45 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:48:48 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:49:51 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying


Jul 18 17:17:10 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:46:43 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:48:49 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying


Jul 19 00:50:01 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:51:16 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:52:52 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 22:13:20 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
```

OR with little more cosmetics:

```
hw067 
Jul 18 14:30:02 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:47:45 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:48:48 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 23:49:51 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying

hw068 
Jul 18 17:17:10 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:46:43 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:48:49 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying

hw069
Jul 19 00:50:01 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:51:16 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 19 00:52:52 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
Jul 18 22:13:20 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001   not responding, still trying
```

Can we achieve this with python Pandas apart from Plain python way. 
- Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag pandas? Do you want a plain text output or a dataframe?

Comment: @xyzjayne, i'm either way okay with any ideas. plain text out is nice even with pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get through itertools and operator function, i'm alos learner and i borrowed the code from one of my POST's ans, However i collected the Few detaild about both the function which may useful i hope.

**itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None or some func)** takes a list of iterables and groups them based on a specified key.
The key specifies what action to apply to each individual iterable, the result of which is then used as the heading for each grouping the items;
items which end up having same 'key' value will end up in the same group.
The return value is an iterable similar to a dictionary in that it is of the form {key : value}.

**operator.itemgetter(n)** constructs a callable that assumes an iterable object (e.g. list, tuple, set) as input, and fetches the n-th element out of it.

**operator.itemgetter(n)** will give you: A function that grabs the item from a list-like object.
Like operator.itemgetter(3) grabs the third item from a list.

More precisely those are callables, not functions, but that is a difference that can often be ignored.

> Below code should be working for you:

```
import itertools
import operator

log_list = []

file = open('file')
for line in file:
    loggs = line.strip().split()
    log_list.append(loggs)

key = operator.itemgetter(3)
# this step is only required if the list is not sorted by the key
log_list.sort(key=key)
for index, logs in itertools.groupby(log_list, key):
    print(index)
    for log in logs:
        print("    " + " ".join(log))
    print("")
```

Result of the above code, i took your file for the test..

```
anujv
    Jul 17 04:34:08 anujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003 not responding, still trying

hw060
    Jul 18 15:46:02 hw060 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying

hw067
    Jul 18 14:30:02 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 23:47:45 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 23:48:48 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 23:49:51 hw067 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying

hw068
    Jul 18 17:17:10 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying
    Jul 19 00:46:43 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 19 00:48:49 hw068 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying

hw069
    Jul 19 00:50:01 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 19 00:51:16 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 19 00:52:52 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 22:13:20 hw069 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying

hw070
    Jul 18 22:13:20 hw070 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 22:17:26 hw070 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying

hw071
    Jul 18 20:16:21 hw071 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 20:17:24 hw071 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 20:18:27 hw071 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying

hw073
    Jul 18 20:43:07 hw073 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying

hw074
    Jul 18 15:45:59 hw074 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 17:17:12 hw074 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying
    Jul 19 01:20:20 hw074 kernel: nfs: server hpstor002 not responding, still trying

hw079
    Jul 18 16:16:01 hw079 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying
    Jul 19 00:17:56 hw079 kernel: nfs: server hpstor001 not responding, still trying

sanujv
    Jul 17 21:18:42 sanujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 01:36:00 sanujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003 not responding, still trying
    Jul 18 04:16:10 sanujv kernel: nfs: server hpstor003 not responding, still trying
```